# Highcharts type is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts

I'm using highcharts-3d in my react webapp.
However, I keep on getting this error once in a while while reloading the page. Can someone help me with this

```html
×
←→2 of 2 errors on the page
TypeError: Cannot read property 'setPaths' of undefined
F.z.step
/Documents/2020Projects/highcharts-3d.src.js:924
F.<anonymous>
Documents/2020Projects/highcharts.src.js:3651
g.objectEach
/Documents/2020Projects/highcharts.src.js:2109
F.animate
/Documents/2020Projects/highcharts.src.js:3639
F.e.animate
/Documents/2020Projects/highcharts-3d.src.js:939
(anonymous function)
/Documents/2020Projects/highcharts.src.js:38977
e.redrawPoints
/Documents/2020Projects/highcharts.src.js:38938
e.render
/Documents/2020Projects/highcharts.src.js:33442
e.redraw
/Documents/2020Projects/highcharts.src.js:33487
(anonymous function)
/Documents/2020Projects/highcharts.src.js:25547
B.redraw
/Documents/2020Projects/highcharts.src.js:25546
B.update
/Documents/2020Projects/highcharts.src.js:35032
(anonymous function)
/src/HighchartsReact.js:55
  52 |   createChart();
  53 | } else {
  54 |   if (props.allowChartUpdate !== false) {
> 55 |     if (!props.immutable && chartRef.current) {
     | ^  56 |       chartRef.current.update(
  57 |         props.options,
  58 |         ...(props.updateArgs || [true, true])
View compiled
```

Im using the below mentioned scripts in index.html

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-3d.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>
```

Comment: If you are using the Highcharts with the React, I encourage to use the official wrapper - https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react If the issue still will occur please reproduce your case with the sample data on some online editor.